# How to build static files for SPA in one docker container and serve it with nginx service in docker compose?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, single-page-application

I am trying to achieve the following. I need to build my Vue app and then serve the static with nginx that is running as a separate service in docker compose.

docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./data/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./data/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
      - admin-dist:/apps/static/admin:ro
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    depends_on:
      - admin
    command: "/bin/sh -c 'while :; do sleep 6h & wait $${!}; nginx -s reload; done & nginx -g \"daemon off;\"'"

  admin:
    build:
      dockerfile: ./apps/Blogue/admin/Dockerfile
      context: ../../
    volumes:
      - admin-dist:/app/dist

volumes:
  admin-dist:
    external: true
```

nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name mydomain.com;
    server_tokens off;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    location / {
      root /apps/static/admin;
      index index.html;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

Dockerfile for vue app

```
# other build steps...

FROM alpine:latest

# # make the 'app' folder the current working directory
WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=installer /app/apps/Blogue/admin/package.json . 
COPY --from=installer /app/apps/Blogue/admin/dist dist

CMD ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
```

So, I can't make it work for a weird reason. Nginx is overwriting the content of the volume with default `50x.html` and `index.html` files and serves them, but not my static files. If I go to Vue container and check the content of the app/dist folder, there will be the same two files, which means that the volume mapped correctly, but I have no idea how to prevent it from overwriting. Maybe, I need some extra step?